# Losing signal from graphic card the moment I start game

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, windows-update

Actuall problem: the moment I start Left4Dead2 game I'm losing signal - monitor say "no singal".

- Windows 10 Pro Version 1703
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600K CPU @ 3.50GHz 3.50
- Graphic Card: NVIDIOA GeForce GTX 980 Ti
- Motherboard: ASUS Z170 PRO GAMING Z170 LGA1151

A more detailed description from potential start:

(this part probably not related) Few month ago my graphic card (GTX 660 Ti) stopped working - I lost signal to monitor the moment I turned on computer. Some tests showed, that card works on other computers, and other cards work on my computer. Problem was not resolved, few days ago I get new but used graphic card.

(more related?) Had problem with game "shadow of mordor" - I were losing signal the moment I started the game. Computer was working well. Left4Dead2 was working well. I managed to fix it, found solution, had to open nvida control panale and change some options for this game, to use this graphic cards. I can't find this solution now so I can't recreate exactly this solution.

(most related?) I updated Windows. For a moment shadow of mordor didn't work like before. Couldn't find the Nvidia control panel. I reinstalled drivers, Shadow of morder is working now. I checked Left4dead2 - not working, like Shadow of mordor before (and it DID work before update!). Uninstalled and installed the newest driver pack form Nvidia, same problem, Left4Dead still give no signal the moment the game start.

With shadow of mordor and other games there IS still sort of problem - for o short moment I'm losing signal from card, monitor "clicks off", but the moment later, game start and I'm getting signal back. So something is still wrong (never before my monitor "clicked off" even for a moment without a reason) but in the end it works perfect.

Still can't find nor install "Nvidia control panel" anymore.

When alredy in game have no problems. Everything works perfect, great details, higs performance, no artifacts, high FPS, no shutdowns, etc. etc.

Comment: If you right click the desktop you could see Nvidia control panel in the list. Do you?

Comment: Also, if it's working OK on the game there may not be an issue at all. Some games will "set things up" the way they want it like resolution, acceleration and other setting when the game starts. It can make the monitor lose signal momentarily. I don't know for sure but something to look into until you get more responses.

Comment: There is nvidia control panel when i click on desktop... Thank you, I was looking for it in search in nvidia folder etc.
Second point - something is wrong. It didn't "lose signal" like this before. But yes, as long as it's working at the end, Ic an live with it.

Thank you

Comment: It could be part of the driver update. Maybe it's seeing up something it missed before? I can only speculate. But, glad you found the control panel to try your diffrent settings.